# python subprocess.Popen blocks in futex_ state

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I'm trying to implement some basic scheduling that spawns maximum n processes.Popen at a time and waits for them to execute. For this I've done:

```
CHECKING_INTERVAL = 10

class StandAloneClient(object):
    """
    Instead of communicating with a backend cluster, fire locally a new thread.
    """
    max_thread_nr = 4
    thread_pool = []
    pending_operations = Queue.Queue(0)

    class OperationExecutor(threading.Thread):

        def run(self):
            """
            Get the required data from the operation queue and launch the operation.
            """
            while True:
                launch_data = StandAloneClient.pending_operations.get()
                if launch_data != None:
                    operation_id = launch_data[0]
                    user_name_label = launch_data[1]
                    LOGGER.debug("Launching operation " + str(operation_id) + " with name " + str(user_name_label))
                    ## Create a new process for the new launched operation
                    oper = ['python', '-m', 'processRunner', str(operation_id), user_name_label]
                    launched_process = Popen(oper, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
#                    launched_process.wait()
#                    while launched_process.poll() is None:
#                        sleep(CHECKING_INTERVAL)
#                        LOGGER.debug("Operation id=%s is still running. Going to sleep for %s seconds."%(operation_id,
#                                                                                                         CHECKING_INTERVAL))
                    LOGGER.debug("===========================================================")
                    LOGGER.debug("Finished operation %s succesfully."%(operation_id,))


    def __init__(self):
        """
        If there are still empty spots create a new executor thread.
        """
        for _ in xrange(self.max_thread_nr - len(self.thread_pool)):
            new_executor = StandAloneClient.OperationExecutor()
            self.thread_pool.append(new_executor)
            new_executor.start()

    @staticmethod
    def execute(operation_id, user_name_label="Unknown"):
        """Start asynchronous operation locally"""
        StandAloneClient.pending_operations.put((operation_id, user_name_label))
```

I'm adding operations to the queue by:

```
StandAloneClient().execute(...)
```

Now I've commented the parts where I tought that might for some reason block the threads. But even so it seems that none of the childs spawned ever end. The execution is done until the end, I've checked the logs and the `processRunner.py` does everything that it needs to do until the end, however if I do a `ps -el|grep python` I still see all the processes spawned:

```
    0 S  1000   755     1  5  80   0 - 548314 poll_s pts/0   00:00:13 python
0 S  1000  1198   755  4  80   0 - 280172 futex_ pts/0   00:00:09 python
0 S  1000  1201   755  4  80   0 - 280176 futex_ pts/0   00:00:09 python
0 S  1000  1206   755  4  80   0 - 280230 futex_ pts/0   00:00:09 python
0 S  1000  1215   755  4  80   0 - 280198 futex_ pts/0   00:00:09 python
0 S  1000  1216   755  4  80   0 - 281669 futex_ pts/0   00:00:09 python
0 S  1000  1221   755  4  80   0 - 280201 futex_ pts/0   00:00:09 python
0 S  1000  1231   755  4  80   0 - 281668 futex_ pts/0   00:00:09 python
0 S  1000  1240   755  4  80   0 - 280229 futex_ pts/0   00:00:09 python
0 S  1000  1257   755  4  80   0 - 280201 futex_ pts/0   00:00:09 python
```

I'm trying this on a fedora 16 machine, with Python 2.7.2. Any suggestions >

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: why do you use subprocess instead of multiprocessing to run Python code in multiple processes? A side note: your code is convoluted for such a simple task

Answer (score 0):

Your threads are not daemons. They continue to live after the main thread exited. They are blocked at `pending_operations.get()` forever.